# How do I use a button to navigate to a website in HTML5?

Tags: html, button

So I want to use a button to navigate to another website. I assume it has something with the "a href" tag to do. Thanks in advance! //Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a button and not just an `<a>` tag

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://example.com'">Navigate!</button>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXtN3/)

Comment: Just as a side note, you can with CSS make the <a> tag look like a button, but this answer is still how you would do it if you were to use a <button> tag

Comment: ^this, 9 times out of 10, I would use CSS.

Comment: The button method requires you to use an `onClick` event and JavaScript. If you can do it in pure HTML, it's marginally faster (and easier to read/maintain)

Comment: Check the other solutions too, they may be better for you. If you end up using my solution though, clicking the green tick on the left would be appreciated :)

Comment: Also, there usually is a aesthetic concern when choosing CSS buttons instead of simpler HTML buttons, because they usually are prettier, they aren't ugly when scaled, and are more easily updated e.g. when you have to change its shape or colors. Read [this article](http://red-team-design.com/just-another-awesome-css3-buttons/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method without Css or javascript

```
<form action="http://example.com"><input type="submit" value="Go somewhere"></form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ccaK/

Comment: Without HTML eh? :P - clever though

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you specifically want a button, you can set a url to `location.href`:

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com'">Visit us!!</button>
```

Btw, try googling stuff first.